# Svelte TypeScript is missing the following properties component

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

```
import Component1 from './Component1.svelte';
import Component2 from './Component2.svelte';

interface complexObject {
    comp1 : Component1
    comp2: Component2
}

let newComplexObj:complexObjects = {
    comp1: Component1, <------ This is where error happens
    comp2: Component2  <------- This is where error happens
}
```

> Type 'typeof Component1__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 'Component1__SvelteComponent_': $$prop_def, $$events_def, $$slot_def, $on, and 5 more.ts(2740)

These are my typescript configurations:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strict": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve"
  }
```

It does render correctly in browser and I get no errors during runtime, but in the IDE it shows me that error.

Comment: By the way, what is the point of passing around the exact component type? If you know the type, you can just instantiate the component directly in the HTML like any other (`<Component1 />`/`<Component2 />`).

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I'm pushing new instances of those components to an array which then gets iterated and rendered. Once rendered I'm taking the user-entered values from those components.

Comment: You probably are. Your array should only contain the underlying data, you then can `bind` that data to the components or use events to update it. [Here is an example](https://svelte.dev/repl/71d90a86d4854db1b1250324188fbc75?version=3.48.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting instances, you setting the constructor which is `typeof`.

```
interface complexObject {
    comp1: typeof Component1,
    comp2: typeof Component2,
}
```

(It is part of the error message, by the way, but easy to miss in all the noise.)